# Angular DI Injection token's type does not match a factory's return value type but service accepts

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, injection-tokens

Why is it possible to provide an injection token of some type but can pass an actual value of a differing type and this be accepted in a service injected with the token?

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';

export const CONFIG = new InjectionToken<string>("SomeToken");
```

```
export interface Config {
    environment: 'someEnv' | 'someEnvTwo';
}
```

```
export function configurationFactory(): any {
    const configuration = {
        environment: 'someEnv';
    }
    return configuration;
}

@NgModule({
    imports: [...],
    exports: [...],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: CONFIG,
            useFactory: configurationFactory
        }
    ]
})
export class SomeModule { }
```

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ConfigurationService {
    constructor(@Inject(CONFIG) private config: Config) {
        const environment = config.environment;
    }
}
```

In this case, the ConfigurationService is injected with the `CONFIG` token that is of type `string` but defines the type as `Config`. In the module it specifies providing the `CONFIG` token and using a value typed as `any` but conforms to the `Config` interface.

Wouldn't the ConfigurationService have a conflict with the token, being specified as type `string`, not conforming to the `Config` type in the construction parameter?

Wouldn't the module's provided `CONFIG_TOKEN` conflict with the factory returning an `any` object rather than a `string`?

Referencing the [Angular DI Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action#supply-a-custom-provider-with-inject) suggests to me that this shouldn't be possible, however this does work.